# Is there a way to get a byte array from image upload in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload an png to the server, so that I can convert it to a base64. I read that it can be done with the Image class, but it is not available in ASP.NET Core 6.

I also read that in order to convert the image to base64, you need a byte array.

My goal is to use that base64 string to store it in a database.

Is there a way to convert a image to a byte array?

```
<pre>
 <form asp-action="MealCreationPage" asp-controller="Controller" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mb-1 row">
            <label for="formFile" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Default file input example</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <input asp-for="ImageU" accept="image/*" class="form-control" type="file" id="formFile">
            </div>
            </div>
<button class="ImportantBtn" type="submit">Registreer</button>  
</form>
</pre>
```

For simplification sake, below is a simplified model that I use for this form.

```
class Model{
public string ImageU { get; set; }
//public IFormFile ImageU { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _"so that I can convert it to a base64 - My goal is to use that base64 string to store it in a database.."_  - **please don't do that**: All databases support _efficient_ storage of binary data directly using `varbinary(n)` types or similar. Base64 is **entirely unnecessary** and wasteful (as it makes all your files 33% larger and impossible to process quickly)

Comment: The app that I am building, will not be that large. Yes, It may be wasteful, but I want search a way to show images in ASP.NET Core 6 in MVC. If you can suggest another way to store and show images, then I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: As far as I know, if you use input upload to upload the image to the asp.net core backend it will store as the byte array, then inside the backend mehotd, you could use IFROMFILE to get it. Why you need to get it again?

Comment: @Hello Storing smallish files in a database table is fine for this scenario, just make sure you're storing and processing files as binary _all the way_ **without** any base64 encoding at any point.

Comment: @Dai Thank you very for the tip. I will do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your controller could look like.

```
public class FileSampleController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Post([FromForm] IFormFile file)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
            byte[] filebyteArr = memoryStream.ToArray();
            // use filebyteArr for saving in database
        }

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is working for small files, if you try to upload larger files you might not have enough space to read them in memory.